# How to animate multiple histograms simultaneously using incremental visualization with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate multiple histograms simultaneously. The animation is intended to incrementally visualize the samples that follow four different distributions (Normal, Gamma, Exponential and Uniform).

I have read and been able to iterate on the matplotlib animation docs' example with multiple subplots using the following thread [Animate multiple shapes in python3 using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609560/animate-multiple-shapes-in-python3-using-matplotlib). However, determining the random variables prior to the "update" function and trying to incrementally update histograms with an animation is causing me issues that I cannot seem to get around. 
Matplotlib version: 3.0.2

## Code that animates a single histogram (that works)

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.random.normal(loc=2.5, scale=1.0, size=n)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

def update(curr):
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-2, 5, 0.5)
    ax1.hist(x[:curr], bins=bins)
    plt.axis([-2, 6, 0, 30])
    ax1.set_title('Sampling the Normal Distribution')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27]) 

a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

## My attempt at animating multiple subplots (does not produce expected result)

```
n = 100

x1 = np.random.normal(loc=2.5, scale=1.0, size=n)
x2 = np.random.gamma(shape=2.0, scale=1.0, size=n)
x3 = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=n)
x4 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high = 5, size=n)

data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
dist = ['Normal', 'Gamma', 'Exponential', 'Uniform']
bins = np.arange(-2,6,0.5) # generate range for bins

# plot the histograms
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

def update(curr):
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    ax1.hist(x1[:curr], normed=True, bins=bins, color='blue')
    ax2.hist(x2[:curr], normed=True, bins=bins, color='red')
    ax3.hist(x3[:curr], normed=True, bins=bins, color='green')
    ax4.hist(x4[:curr], normed=True, bins=bins, color='gray')

a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

## Code that produces expected end result graph (without animation)

```
n = 100

x1 = np.random.normal(loc=2.5, scale=1.0, size=n)
x2 = np.random.gamma(shape=2.0, scale=1.0, size=n)
x3 = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=n)
x4 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high = 5, size=n)

data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
dist = ['Normal', 'Gamma', 'Exponential', 'Uniform']
bins = np.arange(-2,6,0.5) # generate range for bins

# plot the histograms
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.hist(x1, normed=True, bins=bins, color='blue')
ax2.hist(x2, normed=True, bins=bins, color='red')
ax3.hist(x3, normed=True, bins=bins, color='green')
ax4.hist(x4, normed=True, bins=bins, color='gray')

plt.show()
```

## Expected result for multiple subplots (no animation)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TeQH.png)

## Actual result for multiple subplots (with animation)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2glqd.png)

Comment: This task comes from some course homework and there are already plenty of questions about animating exactly this type of plot. [Some here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4124317+*FuncAnimation*+*hist*). Did you look at any of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910622/animation-of-histograms-in-subplot/42912753#42912753 this one helped me solve the issue I was having. Thank you very much for flagging.